# Using paintComponent() on the default JFrame panel

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a gradient background to a JFrame. Within the JFrame, I did not create a JPanel, but rather used the one that is automatically added when the JFrame was created. All the examples I have found online call `paintComponent()` on JPanel instances, but as stated, in my case I didn't specifically instantiate one. I know that `paintComponent()` needs to be called on a component, and therefore can't be called on the JFrame, so do I need to create and add a JPanel in order to achieve this? I've done it this way with success in the past, but I'm trying to keep my code as streamlines as possible, so I don't want to create a second JPanel if I don't need to. Here's the code I have:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JPanel pane;

public Main() {

    int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 400;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    pane.setOpaque(false);
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    // SOME OTHER STUFF
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(255, 195, 225), 0, getHeight(), new Color(139, 207, 236));
    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    paintComponent(grphcs);
    }
}
```

Any help I can get would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so do I need to create and add a JPanel in order to achieve this?

Yes you do.

> but I'm trying to keep my code as streamlines as possible, so I don't want to create a second JPanel if I don't need to.

There's going to be no waste here, since the way to streamline the above code is to get rid of `extends JFrame`. There's no need to do this and many reasons not to. You are painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = 400;
    private static final Color GRAD_COLOR_1 = new Color(255, 195, 225);
    private static final Color GRAD_COLOR_2 = new Color(139, 207, 236);

    public MainPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        // SOME OTHER STUFF
    }

    // to set the preferred size of the JPanel/GUI
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs); // ** don't forget this.
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, GRAD_COLOR_1, 0, getHeight(), GRAD_COLOR_2);
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

        // create the JFrame when/if needed
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

---

> But doesn't it still create unneeded JPanels?

That's worrying about the wrong thing. A single JPanel is created, the contentPane, and this will have no real adverse effect on your program or your use of resources.

> My actual class extends JPanel, so when I instantiate that there is one created, plus the default panel which was created when we created the JFrame.
>   Isn't that kind of the same as what I had before, I mean I could have just created a second JPanel and added it to my main class (JFrame) and called paintComponent() on it.

As mentioned above -- don't make mountains out of molehills and don't do premature optimization. If you're worried about abuse of resources in your program, profile it, and then fix problems that have real effects.

> What are the advantages of extending JPanel instead of JFrame

I mentioned many of them already -- what about my answer above is confusing specifically?

Comment: Thanks, that will resolve my `paintComponent()` issue. But doesn't it still create unneeded JPanels? My actual class extends JPanel, so when I instantiate that there is one created, plus the default panel which was created when we created the JFrame. Isn't that kind of the same as what I had before, I mean I could have just created a second JPanel and added it to my main class (JFrame) and called `paintComponent()` on it. What are the advantages of extending JPanel instead of JFrame?

Comment: @user3226170: see edits. You're falling into a premature optimization trap, and you will want to get out of it.

Comment: I guess what I don't get is when you mentioned that I was forcing myself to  create and display JFrames. I can't display a JPanel without a JFrame, and even in your example a JFrame is created. So why not just make my main class a JFrame and add the panels to it? It just seems to me that the JFrame is base for the window, so why not start with that?

Comment: @user3226170: no, I meant when you were creating a class that **extended** JFrame. Don't do that since that limits the abilities of the class. Always gear towards creating the more flexible JPanel. You will then create a non-extended JFrame when needed.

Comment: @user3226170: you can "just start with a JFrame" but this will force you to create another unnecessary class, even more wasteful if we're counting pennies.

Comment: @user3226170: when extending classes, always ask yourself *why* you're doing this. If you're not overriding any methods of JFrame, you should avoid extending the class. For one, it simplifies your code some.